# Why is a .mp3 passed as an integer?

Tags: android, r.java-file

Maybe this is a really dumb question, but I went through a part of the R.java file. There I saw a mp3 file of my raw folder. It was named:

`public static final int sound01=0x7f040000;`

Why is a sound file passed as an integer? Is that just that they give the file a number, and then Android uses that number as a reference?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is just like any other reference that you access through `R` (e.g. `R.string.x`, `R.dimen.x`). You can access your files in raw through `R.raw.x` (so in this case, `R.raw.sound01`). The integer is just a guaranteed unique identifier for that particular resource.

Comment: Ah, just what I thought, just a reference to the file. Thanks!